# How return image url and prepopulate a form at the same time? Error in image url inside the template

Tags: python, django

I am having a problem to prepopulate a form and also return the image url of the account:

My view:

```
class DadosProfissionaisViewUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
   template_name = 'accounts/udadosprofissionais.html'
   form_class = DadosProfissionaisForm
   model = DadosProfissionais

   def get_initial(self):
       obj = DadosProfissionais.objects.get(user = self.request.user)
       initial = super(DadosProfissionaisViewUpdate, self).get_initial()
       initial = model_to_dict(obj)
       return initial

   def form_valid(self, form):
       obj = DadosProfissionais.objects.get(user = self.request.user)
       obj.user = self.request.user
       obj.nome_publico = form.cleaned_data['nome_publico']    
       obj.nome_consult = form.cleaned_data['nome_consult']
       obj.cep_atend = form.cleaned_data['cep_atend']
       obj.endereco_atend = form.cleaned_data['endereco_atend']
       obj.bairro_atend = form.cleaned_data['bairro_atend']
       obj.save()
       messages.success(self.request, _('Seus dados foram atualizados com sucesso.'))
       return redirect('home')
```

My template:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="text-center">

   <img src="{{ profile_pic.url }}" class="rounded" alt="img">

</div>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

My urls - added MEDIA_URL:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
........
path('sitemap.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')), ]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My form:

```
class DadosProfissionaisForm(forms.ModelForm):
   nome_publico = forms.CharField(label='Nome Público')
   nome_consult = forms.CharField(label='Nome do Consultório')
   cep_atend = forms.CharField(label='CEP')
   endereco_atend = forms.CharField(label='Rua')
   bairro_atend = forms.CharField(label='Bairro')
   profile_pic = forms.ImageField(label='Foto')
   class Meta:
       model = DadosProfissionais
       fields = ['nome_publico', 'nome_consult', 'cep_atend', 'endereco_satend', 
       'bairro_atend', 'profile_pic']
```

I do not know how the correct way to prepolute the form and also load this image profile url in this template. Can anybody give a hand!? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i have some news...
Looking for a way to display the image in a prepopulate form, i read it is not possible because a question of security in django. Well, i will try something else, maybe another template just to change the image without prepopulate it. 
Thanks